# duplicate click-highlighting (CSS class) to corresponding element across multiple SVGs

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have two SVGs with the same elements. When I click an element on SVG1 it's highlighted by toggling a CSS class. I want the same element on SGV2 to be automatically highlighted (NB: later, I'll want to be able to alter what's highlighted on SVG2 by clicking SVG2).

I've tried making a conversion table so when I use getElementById to capture the SVG1 click, that ID is translated to the corresponding ID on SVG2, then apply CSS class, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions on how I should do this?

Here's a JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/scottmclaughlin/gynzou0t/21/

```
    // changes colour of the clicked element
function highlighter () {
        var ellipses = document.getElementById(this.id);
        ellipses.classList.toggle("keyHighlight");

    // also duplicate highlight on second svg
     let duplicateEllipses = (ellipses) => translateTable[ellipses];
      duplicateEllipses.classList.toggle("keyHighlight1");
    }
```

Unrelated, the SVGs should be side by side but the column/row CSS isn't right for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ellipses` is an element not an id, and your `duplicateEllipses` usage is weird, it's defined as a function, but used as an element. The logic way I think you suppose to do is like this:

```
let duplicateEllipses = document.getElementById(translateTable[this.id]);
duplicateEllipses.classList.toggle("keyHighlight1");
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/415osubL/

Answer (score 0):

Use a W3C standard Web Component `<svg-circle-stack>` for each stack of Ellipsis.
(supported in all modern browsers, not in IE)

The WebComponent registers listeners on **every Ellipse** to handle the `click`;
And sends an `Event`, with `index` payload, on every click **to all** Ellipsis.
Ellipsis with **the same index** will also Toggle color.

It doesn't matter *when* you add more `<svg-circle-stack>`; Using `Events` make sure they always work.

[image]

When the `<svg-circle-stack>` is removed from the DOM, it cleans up listeners set outside its own scope on `document`. (the click handlers are cleaned automatically)

Positioning **you do yourself** with CSS Grid or flexbox.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .highlight { fill: gold }
  svg-circle-stack { width:90px; height:180px; display:inline-block; background:pink }
  svg-circle-stack ellipse { fill:white; stroke:black; pointer-events:all; cursor:pointer }
  svg-circle-stack ellipse:hover { stroke:lightgreen }
</style>
<svg-circle-stack></svg-circle-stack>
<svg-circle-stack></svg-circle-stack>
<svg-circle-stack></svg-circle-stack>
<svg-circle-stack></svg-circle-stack>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-circle-stack", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="15 0 100 190">
<ellipse cx="66" cy="45" rx="20" ry="20" />
<ellipse cx="66" cy="95" rx="20" ry="20" />
<ellipse cx="66" cy="145" rx="20" ry="20" />
  </svg>`;
      this.ln = this.querySelectorAll("ellipse").forEach((ellipse, index) => {
        ellipse.onclick = (evt) => {
          ellipse.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("ellipseClick", 
                                     { bubbles:true, detail:index }))
        }
        return document.addEventListener("ellipseClick", (evt) => {
          if (evt.detail == index) ellipse.classList.toggle("highlight");
        })
      })
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
      this.ln.forEach(ellipse => document.removeEventLister("ellipseClick"))
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ooh! that is sweet, didn't know about svg-circle-stack, I'll check it out.

Comment: It is your own home-made **Custom Element**, this native JavaScript API has been around for some years now, not supported in IE. You can built any Element you want with it. eg: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd